# Formatting string in python using .format() but want to keep brackets

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I want to achieve something similar to:

```
user = "The Great User"
text = "Hello {%s}" % user
```

Output:`Hello {The Great User}`

but using .format(). How do I do this? (Note I want brackets around the user)

Comment: To adapt the duplicate to your situation: use `"Hello {{{}}}".format(user)`; you need *doubled* curly braces to include them as literal text, and you need the `{}` placeholder.

Comment: Opps. I was just being stupid. But I will leave the question as it is if someone else gets stupid ;) And Thanks.